# Modified Multinomial formula

Tags: summation, combinatorics

I am trying to compute an explicit formula using Mathematica for the following multinomial expression:

> \begin{equation} \sum_{n_{1}+n_{2}+...+n_{M}=N}^{M} {N \choose
>  n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{M }}  \cdot n_{i} = ? \end{equation}

where $i={1,2,...,M}$ and using

```
multinomial[n__] := (Plus @@ {n})!/Times @@ (#! & /@ {n})
```

but I don't know how make the sumatoria over all the index $n_{k}$.

In fact I know the following:

> \begin{equation} \sum_{n_{1}+n_{2}+...+n_{M}=N}^{M} {N \choose
>  n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{M }}  = M^{N} \end{equation}

but I think that this previous results can not be used in order to obtain the result at the first equation, it's the reason why I am asking for a code in *Mathematica* that tries to compute this thing in an analytical way.

example:

Taking for example M=N=2 and $i=1$ then I have to obtain:

> \begin{equation} \sum_{n_{1}+n_{2}=2}^{2} {2 \choose n_{1},n_{2}} \cdot n_{1} = {2 \choose 2,0} \cdot 2+{2 \choose 0,2} \cdot 0+{2 \choose 1,1} \cdot 1\end{equation}

In fact I I take $i=2$ i would obtain the same:

> \begin{equation} \sum_{n_{1}+n_{2}=2}^{2} {2 \choose n_{1},n_{2}} \cdot n_{2} = {2 \choose 2,0} \cdot 0+{2 \choose 0,2} \cdot 2+{2 \choose 1,1} \cdot 1\end{equation}

Comment: Where is your try in Mathematica?

Comment: the problem is that I don't know how make the sumatoria over all the index for an arbitrary M

Comment: Use $\sum_{n_{1}+n_{2}+...+n_{M}=N}^{M} {N \choose
 n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{M }} x_1^{n_1}\ldots  x_N^{n_N} = ( x_1+x_2+\ldots  x_N)^{N}$, differentiate over $x_1$ and set all $x_i$ to 1.

Comment: I think that your comment is incorrect. In my case n_{i} takes different values inside the summatoria, which are precisely the values for the different index

Comment: I have trouble following your notation.  Would you kindly spell out a small example?  Also for what it's worth: `multinomial[n__] := (+n)!/Times @@ ({n}!)`

Comment: You want an inner sum over the `i` such that the `n_i` sun to `N`?

Comment: I will edit with an example in a moment

Comment: Based @yarchik's comment, the answer is `N M^(N-1)`. Agrees with Mr.Wizards answer `4 3^(4-1) == 108` (although he had m and n switched). Also agrees with your M=N=2 example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that it doesn't matter which index ($i$) one picks, here's a brute force algebraic approach:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_M=N}n_1\binom{N}{n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_M}&=\sum_{n_1=0}^N n_1 \sum_{n_2+n_3+\cdots+n_M=N-n_1}\binom{N}{n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_M}\\
&=\sum_{n_1=0}^N n_1 \sum_{n_2+n_3+\cdots+n_M=N-n_1}\frac{N!}{n_1! n_2!\cdots n_M !}\\
&=\sum_{n_1=0}^N n_1 \sum_{n_2+n_3+\cdots+n_M=N-n_1}\frac{N!}{n_1! n_2!\cdots n_M !}\frac{(N-n_1)!}{(N-n_1)!}\\
&=\sum_{n_1=0}^N n_1 \binom{N}{n_1} \sum_{n_2+n_3+\cdots+n_M=N-n_1}\frac{(N-n_1)!}{n_2!\cdots n_M !}\\
&=\sum_{n_1=0}^N n_1 \binom{N}{n_1}(M-1)^{N-n_1}\\
&=\sum_{n_1=0}^N n_1 \binom{N}{n_1}1^{n_1}(M-1)^{N-n_1}\\
&=N M^{N-1}
\end{align*}

And, yes, I know, this doesn't use *Mathematica*.

Comment: I enjoyed your exposition +1  :)

Comment: Still some niche for us humanoids left. Invigorating (+1). :)

Comment: @gwr It sounds like you watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Pq-S557XQU recently. ;^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I had not, but have now. Maybe we need to implement some Turing test here? I am waiting for Mathematica to tell me, it does not feel like working for me today. Brave new world... :)

Comment: @ubpdqn Good.  My approach was simple brute force but yarchik's approach is much more elegant and useful for many situations.  I hope it gets fleshed out in *Mathematica* terms and posted.

Answer (score 3):

Following Carl Woll's comment, correcting $m$ and $n$, and providing a more efficient form:

```
n = 17;
m = 9;

p = IntegerPartitions[n, {m}, Range[0, n]];

Sum[Total[Permutations[x][[All, 1]] * Multinomial @@ x], {x, p}]

n m^(n - 1)
```

> ```
> 31501343210481297
>
> 31501343210481297
> ```

Solved, it would seem.

Comment: Thanks, but the point is try to obtain an analitic expresion, I am not interested in the numerical evaluation

Comment: You could use [`Multinomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multinomial.html) instead.

Comment: @CarlWoll lol -- I missed that completely; the OP said *modified* multinomial and I just assumed there was a variation, and my memory was too poor to recall the formula without checking.